# How to get list of all non-removable disk device names (SSD/HDD and SATA/IDE only)?

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, scripts, devices

I need a list of all disk device names (not USB or CD ROM) in the following form
DRIVES='sda sdb' so that I can loop through them in a bash script.

Ideal solution would not have to install a special utility and would use /sys|/proc|/dev from the filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recommended solution:

1. Copy the following python script to a file called `internal_block_device_resource`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3

   import os
   import re
   from glob import glob

   rootdir_pattern = re.compile('^.*?/devices')
   internal_devices = []

   def device_state(name):
       """
       Follow pmount policy to determine whether a device is removable or internal.
       """
       with open('/sys/block/%s/device/block/%s/removable' % (name, name)) as f:
           if f.read(1) == '1':
               return

       path = rootdir_pattern.sub('', os.readlink('/sys/block/%s' % name))
       hotplug_buses = ("usb", "ieee1394", "mmc", "pcmcia", "firewire")
       for bus in hotplug_buses:
           if os.path.exists('/sys/bus/%s' % bus):
               for device_bus in os.listdir('/sys/bus/%s/devices' % bus):
                   device_link = rootdir_pattern.sub('', os.readlink(
                       '/sys/bus/%s/devices/%s' % (bus, device_bus)))
                   if re.search(device_link, path):
                       return

       internal_devices.append(name)


   for path in glob('/sys/block/*/device'):
       name = re.sub('.*/(.*?)/device', '\g<1>', path)
       device_state(name)
   print(' '.join(internal_devices))
   ```
2. Ensure the script has executable permission:

   ```
   chmod +x internal_block_device_resource
   ```
3. Set your `DRIVES` bash variable this way:

   `DRIVES=$(./internal_block_device_resource)`

   ```
   $ echo $DRIVES
   sda
   ```

### Initial version:

You need to filter removable devices so you can use this command:

```
find /sys/block/*/device/block/*/removable -exec bash -c 'echo {} | perl -ne "\$a=\$_;s/^\/sys\/block\/(.*?)\/.*/\$1/;print if (\`cat \$a\` == "0")"' \;
```

With a USB stick mounted as `/dev/sdb`, the output is just `sda`.

Comment: suggestion: use awk with FS / and pick the third field for printing. Will avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome.

Comment: @muru: As you said in your answer, the `removable` special file is not so reliable. I'll try to come up with a better solution. (probably not a oneliner this time)

Comment: @muru: If you want to give it a try, the new version is ready

Comment: Thanks @SylvainPineau, your monster one liner seems to work. Not sure if thats the best or canonical solution but hey it works :-)

Comment: Your python3 script still works, i had to add an if query:
"if os.path.exists('/sys/block/%s/device/block/%s/removable' % (name, name)):"
before the "with open.." line, NVMe drives do not have the "removable" file in their device path.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
echo DRIVES=\'`cd /dev; ls sd?; cd`\'
```

It simply goes into the /dev-directory and outputs everything with sd and one more character. After that, it returns to home.

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to set a variable instead of returning a string containing "DRIVES=", you can simply use `DRIVES=\`cd /dev; ls sd?; cd\``.

Comment: it will also include usb sticks... (mounted as sdb for example)

Comment: That's right @JoshuaGleitze, I have tried the obvious but it includes the USB sticks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lsblk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsblk):

```
$ lsblk -o NAME -nl
sda
sda1
sda2
sda4
sda5
sda6
sdb
sdb1
sdb2
sdb5
sdb6
sr0
```

This will include anything worth including. You can use the `-I` option along with the [device types](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lanana/device-list/devices-2.6.txt) to do the filtering.

Comment: it will also include usb sticks and Cdrom... (mounted as sdb/sr0 for example)

Comment: @SylvainPineau I know. sdb here is an USB stick and sr0 is a CD drive. I'd guess that device types can be filtered.

Comment: I think you can use `/sys/block/*/device/block/*/removable` safely

Comment: @SylvainPineau No good. Only sr0 was removable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with standard linux utilities:

```
lsblk -n --scsi --output PATH,RM | \
  grep 0 | \
  awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'
```

`lsblk --scsi --output PATH,RM` will list all SCSI devices along with the path to them and whether they are removable or not.  On my system, it looks like this:

```
/dev/sda  1
/dev/sdb  0
/dev/sdc  0
/dev/sdd  0
/dev/sde  0
```

Removable devices will have a 1 in the second column and non-removable devices will have a 0.  We filter the list to only those non-removeable devices and output the first field which is the path to the device.  This will give you a list like this:

```
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
```

Saving that in a variable will allow you to loop over the path to each non-removable drive in your system.

```
$ export DEVICES=$(lsblk -n --scsi --output PATH,RM | grep 0 | awk '{print $1}')
$ for DEVICE in $DEVICES; do echo $DEVICE; done
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
```